# Order email is not sending to customer mail

Tags: magento2, email, order-email

When a customer place order the email is not sending to customer and store admin.When i checked contact us email it is successfully send.

Comment: have you setup cron ?

Comment: no ,is that required?

Comment: yes it is required , where you site is hosted ? Check this link how to setup cron... http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

Comment: Site is hosted in hostgator..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to setup Cron in Hostegator Account follow this link :
http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/how-do-i-create-and-delete-a-cron-job

and in cron command tab you have to add one by one below ( add and save one by one ) and replace **/var/www/Your-Magento2-Project** in command with your project path / folder name.

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/Your-Magento2-Project/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/magento2/var/log/magento.cron.log
/usr/bin/php /var/www/Your-Magento2-Project/update/cron.php >> /var/www/magento2/var/log/update.cron.log
/usr/bin/php /var/www/Your-Magento2-Project/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/magento2/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

run cron after every 5 minuets or whatever time you need.